# What questions about computer building are on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently, I proposed a stackexhange site for users to come and ask questions about very specific questions about computer building. (would it be safe to mount my motherboard to wood, etc). The proposal was immediately turned down, labeled a duplicate of superuser. Is it? What type of computer building related questions can be asked here, and how will beginning users know that is that type of site, seeing as how it's not marketed/advertised that way? There also seem to be little to no computer hardware related tags.

Comment: Between SU and Hardware Recs, PC building is pretty much covered tight.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it?

Yes.

> What type of computer building related questions can be asked here

Any that isn't specifically excluded or covered elsewhere. The only relevant exclusion in this case would be asking for hardware recommendations, which is covered on hardwarerecs.se

> how will beginning users know that is that type of site, seeing as how it's not marketed/advertised that way?

The [What topics can I ask about here](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) page makes that pretty obvious, methinks:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - **computer hardware**
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking

Computer building is the art of assembling of computer hardware, and since it isn't excluded later on, it's on-topic.

Comment: “Covered elsewhere” is irrelevant. The scope of SU isn't defined by elimination from the scope of other sites. HR was created because SU banned hardware recommendations, not the other way round.